# Orthogonality of curvature and isocurvature fluctuations, but only until horizon crossing?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, cosmological-inflation, axion

I am theoretically investigating our universe with an additional scalar field called axion like particle (ALP). I now want to understand fluctuations in the ALP field, and I am confronted with the terms curvature (adiabatic) and isocurvature (entropy) fluctuations, i.e. my task is to investigate how these fluctuations (probably imprinted by inflation) affect the different momentum modes of the ALP field.

My understanding is the following:
Curvature/adiabatic fluctuations are fluctuations that we see in all fields present, no cancellation of overdensities in one field with underdensities in a different field, so this leads to an actual fluctuation in the total energy density, which means in this region the curvature of the universe changes. Therefore the name 'curvature' fluctuations. This change in the curvature leads to the fact that for such fluctuations the number density relative to the entropy density stays the same, therefore 'adiabatic'.
Isocurvature/entropy fluctuations are fluctuations where an overdensity in one field is cancelled by an underdensity in another field (it even works with one matter field and radiation... in this case the overdensity in the matter field leads to decrease in temperature in the radiation, at least this is how I understand the explanation in Kolb/Turner pg.338)... hence we have no change in the total energy density, the curvature of the universe stays the same (hence 'isocurvature' fl., I guess), but since there are relative fluctuations in the number density, the number density per entropy density does not stay constant (hence 'entropy' fl.).

A first kind of question would be: This sounds like I cannot distinguish curvature and isocurvature fluctuations by looking at the fluctuations in ONE field, but I have to see the whole picture. So I think it probably would make more sense to say 'curvature fluctuations lead to energy density fluctuations in the axion field', than to say 'The axion field has curvature fluctuations', or am I wrong?

*If* my understanding was correct so far, I would say I can naively understand this to this point, but now I have two problems that I am really puzzled about:

1. Why do we say these two kinds of fluctuations are orthogonal to one another? There is Fig.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0009131, where it is pictured that in the field space, the curvature fluctuation is a fluctuation in direction of the background trajectory of the fields, while the isocurvature fluctuation is orthogonal to the background trajectory. How can I see that?
2. It is pointed out quite often that the distinction between the two fluctuations is only import if the modes are super horizon, but not after a mode has entered the horizon. I am totally lost here... when modes are super horizon, I expect NO fluctuations at all, unless they have been imprinted in an inflationary era, when the mode was actually inside the horizon before. (And talking about inflation here: Maybe this leaving and re-entering of the horizon due to inflation is the only reason we actually can HAVE these two kinds of fluctuations?) But again, my main question here is: If the two kinds of fluctuations are orthogonal at first, how can the distinction become useless once the modes entered the horizon??

Sorry for the long question, I would be really happy if someone could help, as you can see: I am confused. :-)